# iOS silencing calls from known callers

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

In iOS 15 I've had a lot of calls from known contacts silenced. This happens at normal times, when my iPhone might be in its sleep/lock state, but not in any of the Focus modes. I do have Silence Unknown Callers turned on, but it says on that screen, "Incoming calls will continue to ring from people in your contacts, recent outgoing calls and Siri Suggestions." (Oxford comma omitted by Apple) Today I had someone also having this experience asking me about it. Neither I, nor the one asking me, recall this happening with earlier versions of iOS.

Can anyone tell me why calls from known contacts are being silenced, & what to do about it?